# Как положить в сессию не весь объект а только 3 поля?

Tags: php, сессия

Здравствуйте

У меня в форме авторизации после всех проверок идет вот такая запись

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
```

в сессию сохраняется весь объект $user, то есть логин, пароль и полностью все данные с записи таблицы.
если записать так:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $user['id'];
```

в сессию сохраниться только его id

Вопрос:
как сохранить в сессию id,login и image? как правильно нужно написать?

прошу помощи в реализации.

Comment: и как лучше? сохранить весь объект, с паролем и всеми данными или все же лучше отдельные поля?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = [
    'id' => $user['id'],
    'login' => $user['login'],
    'image' => $user['image'],
];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SESSION['user']['id'] = $user['id']; // id юзера
$_SESSION['user']['login'] = $user['login']; // логин
$_SESSION['user']['image'] = $user['image']; // картинка
```

Чтобы было ясно, или ниже тоже хороший вариант посоветовали